# JS issue with printing

Tags: javascript

I have a function which takes on some parameters and forwards it to print method.

```
getPrintAction: function () {
    return new Ext.Action({
        scope   : this,
        handler : function () {
            var printRenderer = new BaseRenderer;
            var data = [...];

            var printData = [...];
            printRenderer.print(printData);
        }
    });
}
```

While this works perfectly, when I add an Ajax request, the whole thing breaks.

```
getPrintAction: function () {
    return new Ext.Action({
        scope   : this,
        handler : function () {
            var printRenderer = new BaseRenderer;
            var data = [...];

            Ext.Ajax.request({
                scope  : this,
                params : {...},
                success: function (result) {
                    var printData = [...];
                    printRenderer.print(printData);
                },
                failure: callback()
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I tried to put breakpoints as I thought new `printData` may be causing errors. But that is not the case, `printData` parses `result` from callback and the result is fine. I am getting the right array to forward to `print()` method.

Ultimately it fails here:

```
print: function (component) {

    var win = window.open('','print');

    win.document.write(component); <--- HERE
    win.document.close();
}
```

Where `win` variable is set to `null` if I am going there from request.

I suppose this may be a scope issue but I have no idea how to debug it...

Comment: Where is `windowPrint` called?

Comment: `print()` method has a callback to it, that is all it does. Let me rename it so that it doesn't confuse you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers usually blocks asynchronous calls to `window.open`. You will see at the right of the URL bar a notification about this block.

[image]

That is to prevent spam. You now hate it but trust me that you have been saved of spam because of this a lot of times, so don't hate it.

Such methods needs to be called at the very moment of the click event. If you defer a call to `window.open` in the future, although the callback is created at the moment of the click, it will break.

What you can do is to add another popup that the user will need to click just after the Ajax request. Something like showing a "loading" popup that will change to a "Click here to print" when the load ends.

Comment: This does make sense, but isn't there some more user friendly solution? I mean, I am asking user to click "print" only to be greeted by another "Go ahead and print" message box. So what should be one click, is now two clicks :/

Comment: @Norgul the only other option really would be to open the popup window right away when the click happens, then do your AJAX stuff … and then replace the content in the popup window afterwards (either by assigning a new URL, or populating it via document.write.) Or maybe try to get rid of the popup altogether - and load the stuff that’s to be printed into an iframe instead perhaps? No browser is gonna block you from “opening” iframes whenever you like, directly related to a user interaction or not …

Comment: @Norgul, what 04FS says. In these cases you have to be creative. I don't know what are your exact requirements, but seems the way to go. Opening the window and making the AJAX request afterwards. You can show a "Loading" message inside the opened window content until you replace it.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using iFrames, works like a charm. Thank you